# Can not add table constraint for sdate >= bdate in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Here's the table schema:

```
create table EMPLOYEE
(fname /* Employee's first name */ varchar(15) not null,
init /* Employee's middle initial */ char(1),
lname /* Employee's last name */ varchar(15) not null,
IRD /* Employee's IRD number */ varchar(10) not null primary key, sex /* Employee's sex */ char(1)
constraint check_sex check (sex in ('f','m','F','M')),
bdate /* Employee's birthdate */ date,
office /* Employee's office */ varchar(5),
reg_org /* The number of the registration office the employee works for */
varchar(10),
sdate /* Starting date in the organization */ date);
```

Then I think it make sense to add the constraint

```
alter table employee
add constraint ck_date check (sdate >= bate);
```

but it gives me an error

```
add constraint ck_date check (sdate >= bdate)
               *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02293: cannot validate (SYSTEM.CK_DATE) - check constraint violated
```

Anyone know where I go wrong?

---

update the data of the two columns

SQL> select bdate, sdate from employee;

```
BDATE     SDATE
--------- ---------
21-JAN-58 22-FEB-10
21-MAY-70 17-MAR-09
09-NOV-47 12-MAY-08
10-OCT-53 15-JUN-09
01-OCT-56 01-OCT-05
```

---

```
SQL> select to_char(bdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as bdate, to_char(sdate,'yyyy-mm-dd') from employee;

BDATE      TO_CHAR(SD
---------- ----------
1958-01-21 2010-02-22
1970-05-21 2009-03-17
2047-11-09 2008-05-12
1953-10-10 2009-06-15
1956-10-01 2005-10-01
```

---

---

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've update the question, sorry for the typo

Comment: Can you show us the full 4-digit years? `select to_char(bdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as bdate, to_char(sdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as sdate from employee`

Comment: Are these date columns defined as `varchar`s by any chance?

Comment: There you go. Third line. Case closed.

Comment: I found the problem, one of the bdate is 2047. Thanks you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you probably already have some data in your table, and when you try to create that constraint, the database is trying to validate the values already stored in the table. It seems there is some `sdate` that is `<` than `bdate`.

If you don't want the constraint to be validated during its creation, use:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT ck_date CHECK (sdate >= bdate) NOVALIDATE;
```

**Edit**

As I can in your data, you have, for example, `21-JAN-58` and `22-FEB-10` - I suppose `BDATE` is supposed to be `21-JAN-1958`, and `sdate` - `22-FEB-2010`, right? If you by any chance use the RR format to specify the year, than if the year is less then 50, you get a year after year `2000`, if the value is higher, then you get a year between `1950` and `1999`, check this out:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-49', 'DD-MM-RR'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS year_in_2000,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-50', 'DD-MM-RR'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS year_before_2000 FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
YEAR_IN_2000 YEAR_BEFORE_2000
------------ ----------------
01-01-2049   01-01-1950
```